# NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/HasVirtualAuthenticator error while running test using TestNG and Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, appium

I am trying to create a demo for Mobile Automation using Appium.
Created Selenium-TestNG-Maven framework.
Installed below software for Automation:
1. JDK version- 1.8.0_202
2. Appium version- 1.22.1
3. Android Studio
4 Eclipse - Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

```
Setup Environment variables:
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
PATH
   - JRE : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202
   - Tools : C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
   - Tools/bin : C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
   - Platform-tools : C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Created a Maven project.Below is POM.XML
```

4.0.0
com.Login.Demo
LoginDemoProject
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is the BaseClass.Java

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class BaseClass {
    
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        try
        {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            //caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "OnePlus 7T");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "52a7cc1a");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

            URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
            driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, caps);
        }
    
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //System.out.println("" +e.getCause());
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleTest()
    {
        System.out.println("Test running");
    }
        @AfterTest
        public void teardown()
        {

        }
    }
```

Running BaseClass.Java file using RunAs -> TestNG test but getting below error.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/HasVirtualAuthenticator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at tests.BaseClass.setup(BaseClass.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.virtualauthenticator.HasVirtualAuthenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this problem is related to the selenium version in "pom.xml". You can edit version to 3.141.59. your pom.xml file code updating:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/HasVirtualAuthenticator
```

...implies that the *`HasVirtualAuthenticator`* class definition wasn't found probably as Maven was unable to load the class.

---

### Solution

As per [Class Loading and Forking in Maven Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html) tweaking either the following settings may work:

- *`useSystemClassLoader`*: Setting *'useSystemClassLoader=false'* as follows:

  ```
    <configuration>
      <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
  ```
- *`forkCount`*
- *`useManifestOnlyJar`*

> PS: Ensure that *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).

Comment: I have added ```<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>``` but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and fixed it by modifying the appropriate Selenium compile dependency of Appium that was found in Appium java-client's Maven page. [image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).