# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/HasVirtualAuthenticator with Gradle, Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to this, I want to take html from the url. I decided to try to use Selenium and sketched a service that looks like this:

```
package dataox.keithgellmanrestaurantmenuscraping;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Log4j2
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParserService {

        private final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    
        @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void a() {
            String url = "some url";
            WebDriver webDriver = getWebDriver(url);
            log.info(webDriver.getPageSource());
            quitWebdriver(webDriver);
        }
    
        private WebDriver getWebDriver(String url) {
            WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            webDriver.get(url);
            return webDriver;
        }
    
        private void quitWebdriver(WebDriver webDriver) {
            webDriver.close();
            webDriver.quit();
        }
}
```

When I launch it, I get the following error at the moment "WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options)":

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Failed to invoke event listener method
HandlerMethod details: 
Bean [dataox.keithgellmanrestaurantmenuscraping.ParserService]
Method [public void dataox.keithgellmanrestaurantmenuscraping.ParserService.a()]
Resolved arguments: 

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/HasVirtualAuthenticator
```

I work with Gradle, my gradle.build looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '3.141.59'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.59'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.15.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

What is the best thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Selenium seems heavy handed for the purpose of scraping data.  You could use Jsoup instead.  Your issue may be a duplicate.  Here's a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053080/noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-virtualauthenticator-hasvirtualauthent

Comment: Thanks @neal, but I tried this and also I use Gradle instead of Maven, and maybe because of it these answers are wrong for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. It turned out that it was enough for Gradle to remove the versions altogether. Spring pulls those versions that are relevant for work.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.15.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```